# How to set the position of each cardview inside a recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase

I am making an application that takes all users of a table in `Firebase` and shows them in `CardView`, but I would like administrators to appear before the other users.

For this differentiation, all users were saved to the system with an attribute called `type` which says whether they are normal users or administrators.

This is `TelaChat.java` file:

```
public class TelaChat extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Usuario> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Usuario, ChatAdapter> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        setTitle("Tela de Chat");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cm_rv_membros);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuario");

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Usuario>().setQuery(databaseReference, Usuario.class).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Usuario, ChatAdapter>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ChatAdapter holder, int position, Usuario model) {
            Picasso.with(holder.ivFoto.getContext()).load(model.getImageURL()).centerCrop().resize(140, 140).transform(new ImageTrans_CircleTransform2()).into(holder.ivFoto);
            holder.tvNome.setText(model.getNome());
            holder.tvTipo.setText(model.getTipo());
        }

        @Override
        public ChatAdapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_card, parent, false);
            return new ChatAdapter(view);
        }
    };

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is `ChatAdapter.java` file:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView ivFoto;
    public TextView tvNome;
    public TextView tvTipo;

    public ChatAdapter(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ivFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cc_iv_foto);
        tvNome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cc_tv_nome);
        tvTipo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cc_tv_tipo);
    }
}
```

I've looked for some tutorials on the internet but none has specified what I want to do. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try sorting data by type.

Comment: @AliAli I think so, but I do not know exactly how to do that. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the expected result. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Hi, @AlexMamo! Here is a photo showing my database: https://imgur.com/CtewG78, as you can see, the table with the user data has an encrypted name, the attribute "tipo" (type) is what it says if it is "administrador" (administrator) or "usuário" (user). What I want is that when putting the Cardview into Recyclerview, come before those users who are administrators.

Comment: @AlexMamo More or less, I created an attribute called "order" and put the position I wanted it to appear in the list, then just called with orderByChild ("order"). That's how I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this: orderByChild("type")

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuario").orderByChild("type");
```

Or here:

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Usuario>().setQuery(databaseReference.orderByChild("type"), Usuario.class).build();
```

Sorry I can't test it right now, hope it works.

Comment: Well, it worked out more or less. The idea is for administrators to appear earlier in the list and users soon after, but this way only administrators appear. Can you understand me?

Comment: Ok @PedroSilveira, But the method above to change the order only and do not hide anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea may help in this set a flag for example called position with initial value 0 and create a new list to order on it and check the type and if is an admin add him in the list with position value and increase the position value else add the value without index

```
        private int position = 0;
        private List<Users> myList = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < usersList.size ; i++){

          if(userList.get(i).getType.equal("adminstrator")){

             myList.add(position,userList.get(i))
            position++;

    }else{

       myList.add(usetList.get(i))

     }
    }
```

after set this list "myList" to the recyclerview adapter